# jquery submit form not working action is not working

Tags: javascript, html

## Heading

I'm trying to build a submit form for my login, but I don't know why this action is not working. Any ideas ?

- List item  jquery

  ```
  $(function() {

  var $formLogin = $('#login-form');
  var $formLost = $('#lost-form');
  var $formRegister = $('#register-form');
  var $divForms = $('#div-forms');
  var $modalAnimateTime = 300;
  var $msgAnimateTime = 150;
  var $msgShowTime = 2000;
  ```

  $("form").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
          switch(this.id) {
              case "login-form":
                  var $lg_username=$('#login_username').val();
                  var $lg_password=$('#login_password').val();
                  if ($lg_username == "ERROR") {
                      msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Login error");
                  } else {
                      msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Login OK");
                  }
                  return false;
                  break;
              case "lost-form":
                  var $ls_email=$('#lost_email').val();
                  if ($ls_email == "ERROR") {
                      msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Send error");
                  } else {
                      msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Send OK");
                  }
                  return false;
                  break;
              case "register-form":
                  var $rg_username=$('#register_username').val();
                  var $rg_email=$('#register_email').val();
                  var $rg_password=$('#register_password').val();
                  if ($rg_username == "ERROR") {
                      msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Register error");
                  } else {
                      msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Register OK");
                  }
                  return false;
                  break;
              default:
                  return false;
          }
          return false;
      });

  ```
  $('#login_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formRegister) });
  $('#register_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLogin); });
  $('#login_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formLost); });
  $('#lost_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formLogin); });
  $('#lost_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formRegister); });
  $('#register_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLost); });

  function modalAnimate ($oldForm, $newForm) {
      var $oldH = $oldForm.height();
      var $newH = $newForm.height();
      $divForms.css("height",$oldH);
      $oldForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime, function(){
          $divForms.animate({height: $newH}, $modalAnimateTime, function(){
              $newForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime);
          });
      });
  }

  function msgFade ($msgId, $msgText) {
      $msgId.fadeOut($msgAnimateTime, function() {
          $(this).text($msgText).fadeIn($msgAnimateTime);
      });
  }

  function msgChange($divTag, $iconTag, $textTag, $divClass, $iconClass, $msgText) {
      var $msgOld = $divTag.text();
      msgFade($textTag, $msgText);
      $divTag.addClass($divClass);
      $iconTag.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
      $iconTag.addClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
      setTimeout(function() {
          msgFade($textTag, $msgOld);
          $divTag.removeClass($divClass);
          $iconTag.addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
          $iconTag.removeClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
      }, $msgShowTime);
  }
  ```

  });
- List item html

  ```
              <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
              <div id="div-forms">

                  <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                  <form id="login-form" method="post" action="login.php">
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <div id="div-login-msg">
                              <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                              <span id="text-login-msg">Type your username and password.</span>
                          </div>
                          <input id="login_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                          <input id="login_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                          <div class="checkbox">
                              <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <div>
                              <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                              <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                              <button id="login_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
                  <!-- End # Login Form -->

                  <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                  <form id="lost-form" style="display:none;" method="post" action="submit.php">
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <div id="div-lost-msg">
                              <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                              <span id="text-lost-msg">Type your e-mail.</span>
                          </div>
                          <input id="lost_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <div>
                              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                              <button id="lost_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                              <button id="lost_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
                  <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->

                  <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                  <form id="register-form" style="display:none;" method="post" action="submit.php">
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <div id="div-register-msg">
                              <div id="icon-register-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                              <span id="text-register-msg">Register an account.</span>
                          </div>
                          <input id="register_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                          <input id="register_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                          <input id="register_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <div>
                              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                              <button id="register_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                              <button id="register_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
                  <!-- End | Register Form -->

              </div>
              <!-- End # DIV Form -->

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: can you share form?

Comment: <form id="login-form" method="post" action="login.php"><button type="submit" name="login"class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button></form>

Comment: jquery and html form form action is not working sir

Comment: https://www.proyellowpage.com/category.php?inventory_id=3 click Rate this Inventory live here

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent your form from submitting first before you can run custom code, or else your form will submit before your code runs. This can be done by using `e.preventDefault()`. For example:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is page location login.php

Comment: What do you mean by that?